# Ploting graph with Chart.js using nodejs and moongose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, chart.js

I'm try to plot a graph from a mongodb using `Chart.js` the code `App.js` read the data from mongodb and works fine. The problem occurs when I try to send data to `client side` to plot the graph. What is the best way to send data to cliente side for plot the graph? Below the `graph.ejs` the html file to plot the data.

**App.js**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
    mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

    mongoose.model('Temperatura',
                   new Schema({ time: Number, temperature: Number}),
                   'col');

    var dados = mongoose.model('Temperatura');

            dados.find({}, function(err, data)
            {
                    if(err){
                            console.log(err, data, data.length);
                    }else{
                            console.log(data);
                    }

                    var Time = [];
                    var Temperature = [];
                    var Grafico = [];


                    for ( index in data){

                      var doc = data[index];
                      var objectId = new ObjectID(doc['_id'])
                      var time = objectId.getTimestamp();
                      console.log(doc['temp']);
                      var temperature = doc['temp'];

                      Temperature.push({"value" : temperature});
                      Time.push({"value" : time});

                      }
    }).sort('-date').limit(100);

app.get("/dados", function(req, res){
          res.render('grafico.ejs',{val: Temperature},{ message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
});
```

**Graph.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>myWeather</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    <% } %>
    <h1>Val: <span id="val"><%=val%></span></h1>
    <script>
        var data;
        getData(data);

        var x = data.x;
        var y = data.y;

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: x,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'apples',
                data: y,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
          }]
        }
      });
    </script>
    <canvas id="myChart" syle="width: 80%; margin: 15px auto;"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very vague. Can you please clarify your question so that it focuses on what you're actually struggling with. Are you having trouble sending data or using chartjs? Remember, SO is not an advice forum, it's a QA site.

Comment: @Soviut, my especific problem is send the result of getdata() function to the client side to plot the data using Chartjs.